# Leapfrog integrator, kill off lower order terms

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, computational-physics

Let $H=A+B$ be the Hamiltonian, let $L_A(\cdot):=[\cdot,A], L_B(\cdot):=[\cdot,B]$ denote the Lie derivatives of $A, B$ respectively. We can show that the leapfrog integrator

$$
\exp(\frac{\tau}{2}L_A)\exp(\tau L_B)\exp(\frac{\tau}{2}L_A)
$$

corresponds to motion in surrogate Hamiltonian $H+H_\text{err}$, where

$$
H_\text{err} = \frac{\tau^2}{12}\Big[[A,B],B+\frac{1}{2}A\Big]+O(\tau^3).
$$

Consider a new integrator composed of three successive leapfrog steps, the first of length $a\tau$, second of length $b\tau$, and finally one of length $a\tau$, where $2a+b=1$. Show that there are constants $a, b$ that kill off terms lower than $O(\tau^3)$ in the error Hamiltonian of this new integrator.

I am not sure how to approach this question. I suppose we substitute $\tau \mapsto a\tau, b\tau$ so that our new leapfrog integrator is

$$
\exp(\frac{a\tau}{2}L_A)\exp(b\tau L_B)\exp(\frac{a\tau}{2}L_A)
$$

and we want $a,b$ such that the $\tau^2$ term vanishes. But if we do this then the $\tau^2$ term is

$$
H_\text{err} = \frac{\tau^2}{12}\Big(ab^2[[A,B],B]+\frac{a^2b}{2}[[A,B],A]\Big)
$$

and this only vanishes iff $a=0$ or $b=0$, which isn't what we want.